# Guess the missing alphabet!

Tags: logical-deduction

What is the missing alphabet in below sequence?

M T W T _  _ S

> It is a sequence of a _ _ _ _ :D That's it. Guess it's easy.

Comment: Why - (minus)? is this SHOULD-NOT-ASK question?

Comment: This is a very common question.

Comment: The question itself is fine. I think people are downvoting because the question is too easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

> F S

Because the series is the first letter of

> DAYS IN A WEEK STARTING FROM MONDAY

That is

> Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday

Comment: Just in 1min - got the answer :D Congrats & Marked as Right answer

Answer (score 1):

These are Days in the week , therefor answer will be F (for friday) & S (for Saturday).

Comment: Yes, right! As AeJey answer it first, I marked Right Answer for AeJey. Thanks for answering!